# Firewatir on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, watir, firewatir

I'm trying to use the firewatir on ubuntu and I'm getting the following error:

`irb(main):003:0> require 'firewatir'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir/exceptions
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:inrequire'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir/exceptions.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:inrequire'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir.rb:5:in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:inrescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in require'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in'`

Does anyone have a clue on why this is happening? Did I forget to install anything?

Comment: Check access permissions to file and folders.

Comment: I tried to execute the irb with sudo and it also did not worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firewatir is deprecated. To drive Firefox you should install watir-webdriver. For installation instructions see https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md

Comment: Did you notice that the file is last edited "3 years ago". :) Please do update it. Let me know if you need help with that.